# How to point to project index page by default in XAMPP

Tags: php, web, xampp

i am pretty new this kind of work. I had developed a web app using PHP. i am using XAMPP Server. Now when i am hitting http://www.mywebsite.com/myproject i got my project index page. Now what i looking is if i enter http://www.mywebsite.com it should display myproject's index page.

I am not sure what is this term called. I didn't know how to search for this solution.

Your help will be much appreciated if you can provide the term i should look for or the solution for this.

thanks

Comment: You should edit your virtual host, from apache, to point to the correct folder. Inside your xampp folder you can find a file xampp-virtualhosts.conf (? I guess) which has an example of that. Or, you can simply google apache2 virtual host example or apache virtual host explained.

Comment: [XAMPP official forums](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewforum.php?f=34)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file (which is in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`), edit the `DocumentRoot` property accordingly.

Your current settings are probably looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

which directs you to the main `htdocs` folder. In order to display your project, you use `www.mywebsite.com/myproject`. You should change the `DocumentRoot`. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/your-project-folder"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Tested on Win 8.1 Pro x64, XAMPP 5.6.21 portable. It's working.

Comment: Just as a side note for Mac users this file is not within the XAMPP.app folder, find it at: `~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. The same goes with htdocs, it is under: `~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs` (found from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650354/how-can-i-access-xampp-lampp-folder-via-terminal-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file index.php  from the htdocs in xammp ( ..\xampp\htdocs\index.php)
2. Change the line

header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');

to

header('Location: '.$uri.'/yoursitefolder/');

this will resolve the issue.

Comment: I use the httpd-vhosts.conf for local projects. However, for exposing port 80 to inbound access, I prefer the simplicity of this answer.