# How can I access XAMPP/Lampp folder via Terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal, xampp

I recently started using XAMPP on Mac and it installed the "lampp" folder under "Shared" and showing as an IP address in Finder. So I can access the files via Finder but I'm unable to cd into the folder via Terminal.

The Shared folder is simply not visible. I tried /Volumes to see all volumes, but "lampp" wasn't listed, as well mounting it somehow but that also didn't work. Any ideas? It's so odd that I see the folder in Finder but not in Terminal!

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem the route for htdocs is the following:

```
cd /Users/***your_user_name***/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

"username" only replaces that line by the name of your user

Example, for me it would be:

```
cd /Users/adanuri/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

Answer (score 1):

I run in to the same problem and looked for hours for a solution. I now found this page:
https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html

Since it is a VM you have to click on the Open Terminal button in the general tab of the stack manager. Then a new window opens and you can work on the terminal.

[Screenshot of the stack manager with the open Terminal option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFkEA.png)

[Screen Shot of the open Terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPoum.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the http://localhost version, go and reinstall the non VM XAMPP.

Make sure you download & install a version where the name doesn't include '-VM' here: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

This the path where you can find the full path of xampp htdocs folder.

```
/Users/my_name/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not remember the path of the "htdocs" folder, you could type `ls -a` (ls stands for list) and see even hidden folders and files.

".bitnami" is one of those (inside the user folder) and then follow the path down to "htdocs".

All the other folders, already pointed out by @uriplata in the above answer, are visible simply using the command `ls` each time you change folder (with command "cd").

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the drive:

[image]

When the drive is mounted you can see it at: .bitnami/stackman/machines/volumes/root

If the drive is not mounted root will be empty. However, your data will still be there.

Answer (score -1):

["Open Terminal" XAMPP management tool, see image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx6RQ.png)

You only must clic in "Open Terminal" at XAMPP management tool, as you can see in the attached image.

Comment: you should attach image in your answer