# .htaccess redirect XAMPP Dashboard (http://localhost:8080 ) or specific IP address (http://127.0.0.1:808080) to specific folder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I need to redirect visitors with a specific IP address into a specific folder in the server.

I want **http://127.0.0.1:8080** to redirect me **http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio**

But, when I am putting **http://localhost:8080** or **http://127.0.0.1:8080** in browser it is redirecting me to **XAMPP Dashboard**.

> [image: Screenshot of redirection]

1. Where should I put `.htaccess` file. In the `htdocs` folder or somewhere else?
2. How can I redirect **IP address** to a particular folder instead of **XAMPP Dashboard**?

Comment: if portfolio folder contains your project and if its gonna be only project on your local server...then you can directly put all of portfolio files under htdocs folder....

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362615/9144250 refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing around with `.htaccess files`, why not use apache's vhosts?

in the Apache conf file, uncomment the line that requires in http-vhosts.conf. Then edit that file with something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/your/htdocs/sitename/public"
    ServerName fakedomain.com
    ErrorLog "path/to/error_log"
    <Directory "/your/htdocs/sitename">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        FallbackResource /index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After editing this, you need to edit either `/etc/hosts`, or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. All you do is add the fakedomain like this:

```
127.0.0.1 fakedomain.com
```

Now when you restart your apachea and broswer, you should be able to browse to `http://fakedomain.com` and it will go to the correct project.

> Note: My projects have a public folder where my main entry point index.php sits, which is why you see DocumentRoot with `/public` on the end and Directory doesn't. If yours doesn't just tweak the path to suit!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am using a public IP and Virtual Host is only for local system?

Comment: No, I use virtual hosts on my production servers too

Comment: Your screenshots say 127.0.0.1, since you are running a local xampp

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is only for example since I cannot give IP address here!

Comment: Okay, so can I also use it for virtual hosts in public IP?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. All it does is listen for the domain name. And putting the domain in your hosts file is almost like spoofing the DNS, 'yes you'll find that domain here!'

Comment: but virtual host domain name would not be able to access from other place or from anywhere in the world. Domain must be registered for that.

Comment: XAMPP should *not* be used for production servers! If you have DNS set up then you don't need to edit the hosts file. I only edit hosts file on my dev laptop, not my production servers, since its a real domain with real DNS pointing to the correct IP already.